# Analyse phase of Total Order partitioning

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

[Map Reduce Design Patterns Book](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/patterns/9781449341954/4dot-data-organization-patterns/i_sect14_d1e4430_html)

> You need to run it only once if the distribution of your data does not change quickly over time, because the value ranges it produces will continue to perform well.

I could not get what is meant by the statement, is this like a general observation or can this actually be implemented when using a TotalOrderPartitioner ?

Can we somehow ask the TotalOrderPartitioner to not create a partitioner file and only use one which has already been created ?

Basically can i skip the analyse phase when using a TotalOrderPartitioner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can easily be implemented when using a TotalOrderPartitioner:

```
   TotalOrderPartitioner.setPartitionFile(job.getConfiguration(), partitionFile); // use existing file!!!

   // InputSampler.writePartitionFile(job, sampler); // Just comment out this line!!!
```

Pay attention, from the javadoc:

> public static void setPartitionFile(Configuration conf,
>                                       Path p)
>
> // Set the path to the SequenceFile storing the sorted partition keyset. 
>   It must be the case that for R reduces, there are R-1 keys in the SequenceFile.

If you re-run sorting - if you data changed slightly and the samples should still well represent it - you can use the existing partition file with the samples, as its creation on the client by InputSampler is expensive. But **you have to use the same number of Reducers, as you used in the job for which InputSampler created the partition file.**